# php code to pass id from static navigation bar and select data according to passed id

Tags: php, mysql

table name - News
table column id,cat_id,state_id,city_id

I create a menu which is static.

Now I need to fetch data  according to category, city and state id...

plz tell me how to pass hard coded id from menu bar.Also how to get the selected category or selected city id in variable.

foe ex 
my ID  for category1 = 15
       ID  for category2 = 18

plz help me...if it is possible..

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">category1</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>State</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">state1</a>
 <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>city1</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>city2</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>

         <li><a href='#'>state2</a> </li> 
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>category2</a></li>     
</ul>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Your question is unclear and doesn't provide a specific problem. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question may get you suspended. find answers before asking, that way it won't get repetitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
<a href="index.php?category=10">category1</a>
<a href='index.php?state=4'>State</a>
<a href='index.php?city=1'>city1</a>

$category = $_GET['category'];
$city = $_GET['city'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
```